# SharePoint detailed errors are not shown

Tags: web-config

I have the following settings in my Web.Config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and

```
CallStack="true"
```

But still detailed errors are not shown (the default error message asking us to make the above changes to show detailed error). These settings seem to work for MOSS 2007 but not for SharePoint 2010. I have the same issue with two different servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really confusing in SP2010, but you need to change the following web.config.

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config"

Comment: That's only if you're trying to get error details for application pages though

Comment: Exactly right wictor, as _layout is an application vdir in iis it has its own web.config

Answer (score 3):

Those changes should do it, even though I usually add debug="true" as well. Also make sure that you're editing the correct web.config (correct iis web application, or the correct one in the SharePoint root).

Comment: Thanks Victor. I was about ti post about debug=true. I checked it and it is in debug mode. Everything seems correct but still does not work.

Comment: What URL are you receiving the error on and what web.config file have you changed?

Comment: Muhimbi'sanswer solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the error occur? Sometimes you have to change it in different web.config than the one for your web application. The 14 hives contain a lot of folders with other web.configs.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a corrupt web.config file. Check the windows event application logs to see what the actual error is. (from your other question i assume you are modifying the web.config on one of you web applications)